# Strange URLs from wordpress - can't 301 redirect

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect

I am finding that Google is indexing some very strange URLs from my Wordpress site

The page URL is:
https://www.bennettsfunerals.co.uk/arranging-a-funeral/your-guide-to-arranging-a-funeral

However Google is finding URLs like:
https://www.bennettsfunerals.co.uk/arranging-a-funeral/your-guide-to-arranging-a-funeral/?pagename=arranging-a-funeral%2Fyour-guide-to-arranging-a-funeral

any attempt to 301 redirect this URL is failing and i cant find the root cause the problem

is this something anyone has seen before and how can i get around this problem

THANKS!!!!

Comment: Can you show what 301 redirects you attempted?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this Javascript redirect.

// Javascript URL redirection - generated by www.rapidtables.com
    window.location.replace("https://www.bennettsfunerals.co.uk/arranging-a-funeral/your-guide-to-arranging-a-funeral/");